# Global name not defined, is this a syntax error?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have been working with classes, and I have fixed several mistakes related to indentation, but in this case I have been checking all the possible errors. It might be a concept error. If someone can tell me what is my mistake, it will be very helpful.

From this code, I get the error **"NameError": global name 'vector' is not defined**

```
import qgis
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface

class Varias_Funciones:

         vector = QgsVectorLayer("ROUTE","Municipios","ogr")

     #LA CLASE TENDRA LA CAPACIDAD DE ENTRAR EN EL INTERFAZ DE QGIS
         def __init__(self, iface):
             self.iface = iface

     #CARGA DE LA CAPA DE MUNICIPIOS (CAPA VECTORIAL)
         def capa_vectorial(self):
             QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vector)

     #CARGA DE LA CAPA DE RASTER MTN50
         def capa_raster(self):
             raster = QgsRasterLayer("ROUTE", "MTN50")
             QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([raster])

     #CARGA DE SISTEMAS DE COORDEANDAS
         def coordenadas(self):
             crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4258, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId)
             vector.setCrs(crs)

     #ABRIR LAS PROPIEDADES
         def abrir_propiedades(self):
             self.iface.showLayerProperties(vector)


comprobar_funciones = Varias_Funciones(qgis.utils.iface)
comprobar_funciones.capa_vectorial()
comprobar_funciones.capa_raster()
comprobar_funciones.coordenadas()
comprobar_funciones.abrir_propiedades()
```

Comment: Is this a standalone script or for the command line in qgis? Standalone it won´t work this way.

Comment: well, I was writing in Python IDLE, then open it in Text Editor in QGIS

Comment: try using `self.vector` instead of `vector` in coordenadas() ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a basic problem of creation of a Class.

`vector = QgsVectorLayer("ROUTE","Municipios","ogr")` is a class variable defined inside the class

You can access it with:

```
class myclass:
    vector = QgsVectorLayer("ROUTE","Municipios","ogr")
print myclass.vector
<qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer object at 0x1154d55a8>
```

If I use part of your class

```
class Varias_Funciones:
     vector = QgsVectorLayer("ROUTE","Municipios","ogr")
     def capa_vectorial(vector):
         return QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vector)

 layer = Varias_Funciones
 layer.capa_vectorial()
 ....error...
```

You should use theoretically

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(Varias_Funciones.vector)
```

But it is not correct and that is why a class has constructor or initialization method that Python calls when you create a new instance of this class.

```
class Varias_Funciones(object):
    def __init__(self):
       self.vector = QgsVectorLayer("ROUTE","Municipios","ogr")
    def capa_vectorial(self):
      return QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(self.vector)
```

Then

```
 layer = Varias_Funciones()
 layer.capa_vectorial()
 # or directly
 layer = Varias_Funciones().capa_vectorial()
```

work

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation. I will test it during this afternoon. I completely understood it, actually, I got "something" like your code because I kept working on it... well, I wasn't in a bad way at all. 
Thank you again